# My array is too large to be allocated. What can I do to split it into smaller chunks? I cannot use split() as I cannot allocate a vector of 128.0 Gb

Tags: r, arrays, ncdf4

I have an array of length num [1:584, 1:712, 1:30, 1:365]. This array contains calculations from a model run. The array contains: [longitudes, latitudes, years, days].

I tried to save the data to an .nc file using ncvar_put but I got the error:

`Error in ncvar_put(nca, my_variables, my_data_array) :  long vectors not supported yet: ../include/Rinlinedfuns.h:537`

So I need to split the array. Following google searches, I tried to use:

```
#clear all data frames from environment to save memory
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class) == "data.frame"])

#splitting the my_data_array along 3 year periods (5y = 1095 days) 
chunk_length = 1825
split (Q0d_ym,
       ceiling(seq_along(Q0d_ym) / chunk_length))
```

which led to the error:

`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 128.0 Gb`.

MRE:

```
lons <- 583
lats <- 712
my_data_array <- array(0.,c(lons, lats, 30, 365))
#splitting the my_data_array along 3 year periods (5y = 1095 days) 
chunk_length = 1825
split (my_data_array,
       ceiling(seq_along(my_data_array) / chunk_length))
```

Any ideas would be gratefully received. I did try to split the array into even smaller chunks but I got the same error. I could run my model again in smaller chunks, but if there is a way to split my current array into smaller chunks which I can then save to an .nc file that would be preferable (particularly due to time taken to run the model).

Comment: The Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect, please check the tags suggested before posting your question. In this case, the [tag:rstudio] tag is purely for issues relating to the IDE itself and has nothing to do with the R programming language. I'll suggest an edit to your question removing those tags, please let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Realize that if you start with a large object, trying to `split` it will at-least _double_ the amount of RAM you need, since the split-object will be a _copy_ of the data, the splitting is a copy-on-write operation, it does not work on the data in-place. I suggest one way you can try to work on this is to step back to how you imported the data in the first place, and figure out how to read in partial chunks at a time instead of the whole corpus.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your comments. I am new to SO so getting familiar still with conventions e.g. tagging - thanks for the info. I think best thing to do will be for me to re-run my model in smaller chunks, time consuming though that may be. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is a .nc file a requirement? Does the .nc file have to have any particular structure? Is the .nc file going to be processed outside of R?

Comment: @jblood94 I am processing the data in GIS, so ideally a GIS-compatible file. Given .nc files are great for holding spatio-temporal data, I think it is a requirement in my case.

Comment: That helps. Does the file need to have a particular structure?

Comment: The file structure is as follows: `#-define dimensions and variable
dimLatitude<-ncdim_def(name = 'lat',units = 'degrees_north', vals = LAT) 
dimLongitude<-ncdim_def(name = 'lon',units = 'degrees_east', vals = LON) 
dimTime<-ncdim_def(name = 'StdTime',units = 'days_since_1970', vals = 1:1825,unlim = TRUE)
my_variable <- ncvar_def(name='variable', units ='', dim = list(dimLongitude,dimLatitude,dimTime),missval = -9.96920996838687e+36)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `start` and `count` arguments of `ncvar_put` to write out chunks in a `for` loop. This seems to be working for me:

```
library(ncdf4)

lons <- 583
lats <- 712
LAT <- runif(lats)
LON <- runif(lons)
my_data_array <- array(0, c(lons, lats, 30, 365))
dimLatitude <- ncdim_def(name = 'lat', units = 'degrees_north', vals = LAT)
dimLongitude <- ncdim_def(name = 'lon', units = 'degrees_east', vals = LON)
dimTime <- ncdim_def(name = 'StdTime', units = 'days_since_1970', vals = 1:(30*365), unlim = TRUE)
my_variable <- ncvar_def(name = 'variable', units = '', dim = list(dimLongitude,dimLatitude,dimTime), missval = -9.96920996838687e+36)
nc <- nc_create("C:/test.nc", my_variable)

for (i in 1:30) {
  ncvar_put(nc, my_variable, my_data_array[,,i,], start = c(1, 1, (i - 1L)*365L + 1L), count = c(lons, lats, 365))
}

nc_close(nc)
```

Comment: This has worked for me as well, thank you for your help!